# AMP cache ping request rate

Tags: amp-html

Is there a need to throttle requests to the AMP ping url?  I have an infrequent case where a page change may need to update the cache for about 20,000 urls. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping) does not indicate if requests to the ping url should be throttled though.

In my case, the requests would be made in serial, so I doubt the load would be any issue.  I just want to be sure it's allowed and I don't start getting rejected for exceeding an undocumented limit.

Comment: I think it is ok, just don't let your AMP hit the quota limits. Just remember that the AMP URL API has a quota of 1,000,000 Request per day and 1,000 Request per 100 seconds, you can also check it in this [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/limits). You can double check it in your Developer Console. For more information, check this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cache-guidelines.md) about AMP Cache

Comment: @KENdi, that's just what I was looking for.  I hadn't seen that usage limits page you referenced.  Thanks!  Would you please move this comment to an "answer" so I can mark it as the correct answer so others see it as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is ok, just don't let your AMP hit the quota limits. Just remember that the AMP URL API has a quota of 1,000,000 Request per day and 1,000 Request per 100 seconds, you can also check it in this [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/limits). You can double check it in your Developer Console. For more information, check this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-cache-guidelines.md) about AMP Cache